# P-chanel MOSFET series configuration

Tags: batteries, mosfet, ups

Good day

I'm busy designing a small DC UPS to run some appliances when the power goes out. I am, however, having trouble with an element in the battery switch-over circuit.

I decided on using a circuit configuration similar to those that were discussed [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/96059/switch-between-battery-and-usb-power-no-microcontroller-circuit), [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/130932/switching-between-battery-and-usb-using-diode-or-logic/212580#212580) and [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/100118/switching-arduino-atmega-to-sleep-mode-when-on-battery).

I learned that replacing a diode with two opposite facing series-connected MOSFETS has the great advantage of a much smaller voltage drop, while still being able to block reverse currents when the devices are in the off state.

My question is: Does it matter which way around the MOSFETS are connected (e.g. source-to-source or drain-to-drain)? I have seen them being used in both configurations. Could somebody please explain the difference to me?

Please refer to the attached images to clarify my answer.[image]
[image]

I am aware that the voltage difference between the two sources will allow me to just use or'ing diodes, but I need the voltage drop advantage on the battery side, unless there is a simple way to construct "ideal" diodes that can be used in stead. Unfortunately I am limited to through-hole components.

I am looking forward to any answers and responses. 
Reinforcing critics on my circuit design is also most welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there will be any difference between the circuits.

In principle a MOSFETs drain and source are equal, like this:
[image]
See, no physical difference !

**But** many discrete (power) MOSFETs are build such that the Drain can take a higher voltage. To keep Rds_on low, the same changes are **not** applied to the source.

Then there is the body, bulk or substrate (different names but same thing), both source and drain have a diode to substrate (N+ to p junction as in picture). In discrete MOSFETs the bulk is almost always connected to the source resulting in another difference ! The result is that only the drain-substrate diode remains but since substrate is connected to the source, the diode is now between drain and source ! When you would use only one NMOS in your circuit, how you connect the drain and the source **would** matter.

But you have two mosfets in (anti) series one drain-source diode will conduct but the other diode will be in reverse and make the open circuit.

So in my opinion, both circuits will work equally well.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. It is very insightful. Would the gate voltage required to trigger the devices be the same in both cases?

Comment: Yes, it will be the same. As long as Vgs is much larger than the Vt (threshold voltage) of the MOSFET it will switch on. In your circuits this is the case.